# SVN doesn't remember my credentials

Tags: svn

I'm evaluating www.assembla.com that offers free private 2gb SVN repository. I have created repository and checked it out without a problem with my MacOS Snow Leopard. But any SVN operation (like svn ci, svn up etc) asks me a password again without remembering it. So i’m doing “svn up” and i see:

```
Error validating server certificate for ‘https://subversion.assembla.com:443’:
– The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority.
Use the fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
...
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

I press “p” and i see:

```
password for ‘eye’:
```

Where ‘eye’ is my logged-in macos user. I need to press Return here to get a username and pasword prompt – after that svn comand works fine. The problem is – if i issue second svn command a second later i’m asked about certificate, login and password AGAIN :(. It’s a first time i see such problem – my svn operations with my own servers and third-party svn servers are flawless on same pc, certificate/login/password are remembered and never asked again. Any hints why "(p)ermanently" don't remember a certificate and login/passwort are not remembered are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's internal MacOS error. After installing a fresh copy of MacOS all works fine with built-in subversion client :(.